# Android OnBootReceiver Crashing Exception NullPointer

Tags: java, android, cursor, broadcastreceiver

My On Boot Receiver keeps crashing  :

```
   01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.prva.OnBootReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2043)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:132)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1098)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at com.example.prva.DatabaseManager.getAllData(DatabaseManager.java:91)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at com.example.prva.OnBootReceiver.onReceive(OnBootReceiver.java:32)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2028)
01-06 03:20:13.861: E/AndroidRuntime(15832):    ... 10 more
```

Broadcast receiver :

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();               
        int hour = c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sek = c2.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        int dan;
        int dodaj;

        milivreme = ((hour * 60 * 60 * 1000)+ (minute * 60 * 1000) + (sek * 1000));

        Cursor cursor = DatabaseManager.getAllData();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {               
        milibaza = cursor.getInt(2);
        razlika = milibaza - milivreme;

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 3, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + razlika, pendingintent);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close(); 
    }
```

The getAllData method :

```
public static Cursor getAllData() {

        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO }, 
                null, null, null, null, null);       

    }
```

Databse has records :

I have a button which displays last value from the database in a textview :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String BazaDan;
                int BazaVrijeme;
                DatabaseManager.Cursoric();

                BazaDan = DatabaseManager.getDan();
                BazaVrijeme = DatabaseManager.getVrijeme();
                textbaza.setText(new StringBuilder(BazaDan).append(", ").append(BazaVrijeme).toString());
            }
        });
```

Method for Cursor that button is using :

```
public static void Cursoric(){

        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.query
                (
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO },                       
                        null, null, null, null, null
                );
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                BazaDan = cursor.getString(1);
                BazaVrijeme = cursor.getInt(2);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }    

        cursor.close(); 
    }
```

As you can see its almost the same thing I'm using in BroadcastReceiver.
The textview after that button click displays from the database (last time I tested) :

```
1, 12120000
```

Its day number, and miliseconds.

So records are being stored in the database, and they can be retrieved but OnBootReceiver keeps getting null pointer exception when booting while he is doing almost the same thing with cursor as that button.

Comment: where is DatabaseManager class i think for create or accessing database we will need to pass Context to database class so make sure you are passing it ? and plz post full log

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Full log posted. My DatabaseManager class creates and handles the database (those methods I'm calling getAllData are from it).

Comment: what is 91 line num in DatabaseManager class?

Comment: Number 91 and 92, the getAllData method : `return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO }, 
       null, null, null, null, null); `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Cursor cursor=""; Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Cursor

Comment: try this code `public static Cursor getAllData() {
      Cursor cursor=null;
       if(db!=null){
           cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO }, 
                null, null, null, null, null); 
         }
        else{
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO }, 
                null, null, null, null, null); 
        }
        return  cursor;     

    }   `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); Cannot use this in a static context

Comment: then comment else part and just put an log inside else block

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Same error caused at line on else block.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I just commented SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); else is the same

Comment: friend just remove else part or comment it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in log :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

because db instance is null inside `getAllData` method so just make null check before using it as :

```
public static Cursor getAllData()
{
       Cursor cursor=null;
    if(db!=null)
    {
      cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] 
              { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, 
              TABLE_COLUMN_TWO }, null,
               null, null, null, null);
    }

return cursor;
}
```

and also check cursor for NULL before using it inside `onReceive` method of `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would move all of your code to another procedure - **Broadcast Receivers run a maximum of 10 seconds (currently) and then terminate**! [See this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460284/broadcastreceiver-vs-service).   [And This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Any code left unprocessed will remain so.  This is especially important to understand when performing database operations.

Your null pointer exception is likely your cursor, but you need to test to determine what is null.  You also may want to wrap your code in an error trap when making calls that cannot complete or incur an error - like your database operation.

Just some suggestions to help you resolve your issue and make your code more stable.